# Method Not Allowed (POST): /items/

Tags: python, html, django, post

So i'm trying to do a filter with django, to filter the items on the main page. A little context:

An item can be assigned to a user or not. I want a filter, to see what items are assigned and which items aren't.

**This is my function in** `views.py`:

```
class ItemsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'inventory/items.html'
    context_object_name = 'items_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        if (self.request.user.is_authenticated):
            
            if self.request.method == "get":
                searched = self.request.GET.get('searched')
                
                if searched == "None":
                    return Item.objects.filter(assigned_user__isnull=True, company=getCompany(self.request.user))
        
                else:
                    return Item.objects.filter(assigned_user__isnull=False, company=getCompany(self.request.user))
            
            else:
                return Item.objects.filter(company=getCompany(self.request.user))
```

**And this is from my** `items.html`:

```
<form method="post" action="/items">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="item_filter">
        <option value="None">Not Checked In</option>
        <option value="Checked_In">Checked In</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="filter">
</form>
```

So basically what i want is, that the user can pick one of the two choices in the dropdown-menu, and the items should be listed based on the choice he made.

When i use this form and click the submit button, the screen gets white and in my console, the error
**`Method Not Allowed (POST): /items/`** appears. Has this something to do with the fact i'm using the `generic.ListView` for my view?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, ListView has only GET method implemented, if you want you can declare post method with required logic needed in your view returning HTTPResponse and it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in list view is POST not allowed. But you dont need it:
In template:

```
<form action="/items">
    <select name="item_filter">
        <option value>Not Checked In</option>
        <option value="Checked_In">Checked In</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="filter">
</form>
```

in view:

```
class ItemsView(ListView):
    ... # any staff

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = {'company':getCompany(self.request.user)}
        if (self.request.user.is_authenticated):
                query['assigned_user__isnull'] = bool(self.request.GET.get('item_filter'))
        return Item.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: Hey, thank's a lot for the answer. i have a short question. This solution looks very good, but when using it, i get an error that says "assigned_user__isnull is not defined". I already tried some things, but they didn't work. What am i missing?

Comment: i update answer